# Open modal on specific id

Tags: javascript, php

I've a script that gives a button a specific id `<button id='myBtn$i'>Open Modal</button>`, $i goes with the for loop. With that specific id I should be able to open specific modals with the same $i `<div id='myModal$i' class='modal'></div>` . With this javascript

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal$i');

var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn$i');

var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[$i];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't succeed, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: `$i` variable or a string ? kindly show your html and for loop also

Comment: $i = 0 ; so $i is a variable from 0 to 23

Comment: your ids like `myBtn0`,`myBtn1` etc right

Comment: @prasad that's right!

Comment: see My answer .

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Declare the variable as a global. And Do with **[addEventListener()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)**

```
 var modal;
    var btn;
    var span;
    for(var $i=0; $i<23; $i++){
     modal = document.getElementById('myModal'+$i);
     btn = document.getElementById('myBtn'+$i);
     span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[$i];
   
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    })
    span.addEventListener("click", function() {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    })
}
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work.. I have implemented the code outside the php and inside the php. I've the $i in the while loop as $i = -1 ; and when it goes in the while loop it starts with $i++ so 0 till 23.. When I try to make the variable global it shows a white screen

Comment: `$i` is the  php variable or js variable